# Sending an array in XMLRPC?

Tags: php, xml-rpc, xmlrpcclient

I cant figure out whats wrong with this:

```
$message = new xmlrpcmsg('service.RegistrationDetails',
    array(new xmlrpcval(
         array('EventId' => new xmlrpxval($EventId, "int"), 
             'ParticipantId' => new xmlrpxval($usrId, "int")), 'array') 
    )
);
```

its as per the documentation on - http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlrpcval.html

but the above crashes

```
$result = $server->send($message);
```

I tried:

```
$message = new xmlrpcmsg('service.RegistrationDetails',
    new xmlrpcval(
         array('EventId' => new xmlrpxval($EventId, "int"), 
             'ParticipantId' => new xmlrpxval($usrId, "int")), 'array') 
);
```

but that didnt work either

---

my bad! i had a typo in there - "xmlrpxval" instead of "xmlrpcval". i think the second should work, but not sure...

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"?  Do you get an error?  A segfault?

Comment: hey - umm - sorry, php just stops.

Comment: Crank `error_reporting` all the way up to `-1` and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked perfectly:

```
$message = new xmlrpcmsg('abc.abcDetails', array(new xmlrpcval($cId, 'int'), new xmlrpcval($dStr,'string') ));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because what you're trying to define is not actually an array, it's an associative array. Use `struct` instead of `array` and it should work.